# Recurring Selection of rows based on value of the value in previous row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the typical emp table from which i want to fetch the hierarchical organisation chart of the employee specified.

i.e. if I Enter 101 as the EMPID in where clause then it should show:

```
ID  NAME   MGRID
101 SCOTT   104
104 TIGER   106
106 KING    ---
```

I want to know if it can be solved with SQL or I have to use PL/SQL ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, mgrid
FROM emp
START WITH id = 101
CONNECT BY PRIOR mgrid = id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Great.SQL has the power to do this!!  
No need to  
    `order by id`  
as it gives  
    `EMPNO ENAME MGR

    7782 CLARK 7839
    7839 KING ---
    7934 MILLER 7782`  

which places record to be shown in last in middle.

Comment: @cyborg007: never, ever rely on a sort order unless you have an `order by` in your statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I mean the records when sorted are not in the way I expect because in the table random entries are there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using oracle, I think Hierarchical Queries are just what you need:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm